# 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I want to use the images stored in a dictionary, to convert it to a GIF. The images in the dictionary is like this type:

```
people={
    1: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x10962C510>,
    2: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F90>,
    3: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F50>}
```

I think is a Pillow image. But why do I always get this error:

> 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'

What does it mean?

The full error:

```
File "/***view.py", line 266, in convert_gif
    new_frame = Image.open(imgs[count])
File "/***/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2775, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read' –
```

The code:

```
self._images = { 
    people: {
        1: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x10962C510>, 
        2: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F90>, 
        3: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F50>
    }
}

def convert_gif(self):

    imgs = self._images["people"]
    number = len(imgs)
    count=1

    while count <= number:
        new_frame = Image.open(imgs[count])
        self._frames.append(new_frame)
        count += 1

    self._frames[0].save('png_to_gif.gif', format='GIF', append_images=self._frames[1:], save_all=True, duration=300, loop=0)
```

Comment: people = {1: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x10962C510>, 2: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F90>, 3: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F50>}

Comment: Please show the full error traceback.

Comment: What is `self._images`?

Comment: Try `new_frame = imgs[count]`

Comment: self._images = {people:{1: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x10962C510>, 2: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F90>, 3: <PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGBA size=16x16 at 0x1098D7F50>}}

Comment: File "/***view.py", line 266, in convert_gif
    new_frame = Image.open(imgs[count])
  File "/***/python3.7/site-packages/PIL/Image.py", line 2775, in open
    prefix = fp.read(16)
AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: As @JustinEzequiel has observed, in line `new_frame = Image.open(imgs[count])`, `imgs[count]` is _already_ an `Image`, so this line is unnecessary.

Comment: or you can use : `self._frames.append(new_frame.copy())`

Answer (score 7):

As others have pointed out in the comments, the problem is this:

```py
imgs = self._images["people"]
...
new_frame = Image.open(imgs[count])
```

The error comes from [`Image.open`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.open), which expects you to pass it a filename, a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-file-object), or a [`pathlib.Path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path) object as the 1st positional argument:

> `PIL.Image.open(fp, mode='r', formats=None)`
>
> `Parameters`
>
> `fp` – A filename (string), pathlib.Path object or a file object.
> The file object must implement `file.read`, `file.seek`, and `file.tell` methods, and be opened in binary mode.

In Python, file objects have a [`read` method](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.read), and `Image.open` simply calls that `read` method on the passed file object. It reads the image file and converts it to an `Image` object.

But if you check the type of `imgs[count]`, it *already* is an `Image` object.

```
curr_img = imgs[count]
print(curr_img)  
# <PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=240x160 at 0x7F5C00B74588>
```

And [`Image` objects](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#functions) don't have a read method, and they shouldn't have one because the image data is already loaded into memory. You can now use `Image`-related functions on the object, like appending them to a list to create a GIF.

So simply remove the `Image.open` call and it's going to work as expected.

```py
while count <= number:
    new_frame = imgs[count]
    self._frames.append(new_frame)
    count += 1
```